# How to avoid "line is longer than 80 characters" for my SVN embedded $Id$ property?

Tags: java, maven-2, checkstyle

This is my `foo.java` file:

```
/**
 * LICENSE blah-blah-blah
 * @Version $Id$
 */
public class Foo {
}
```

This is how the file looks after `svn update`:

```
/**
 * LICENSE blah-blah-blah
 * @Version $Id: Foo.java 396 2010-10-14 06:31:27Z myname@my-very-long-domain.com $
 */
public class Foo {
}
```

The length of line no.3 is over 80 characters and I can't do anything with this, since the value is embedded by SVN. `maven-checkstyle-plugin` complains with:

```
Foo.java:3: Line is longer than 80 characters.
```

Is there anything I can do with this? Can I teach `checkstyle` to ignore just this particular line?

Comment: IMHO, the `$Id$` info adds no value whatsoever and often leads to really annoying merge conflicts (this line has always changed in both branches if the file was changed in both, and cannot be automatically merged). It's a relict from pre-source control times; the version and change history is easily accessible through SVN itself. I'd just get rid of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html) there is it possible to ignore lines with a particular pattern. So this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `ignorePattern` to the `LineLength` module in your Checkstyle Checker configuration file so that it ignores the line containing version information.

```
<module name="LineLength">
  <property name="severity" value="inherit"/>
  <property name="ignorePattern" value="^ \* @Version \$Id: .*$"/>
</module>
```